# How to configure Sublime Text not to remember files and unsaved changes between sessions?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Between sessions, Sublime Text remembers which files I have open (and unsaved changes to them). How can I make Sublime Text forget about these between sessions?

Comment: Why did you say that *This post does not meet our quality standards.*?

Comment: This question concerns a "software tool commonly used by programmers" and is "a practical, answerable problem" thus it is on topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Preferences -> Settings - Default** there are attributes that you have to disable:

```
[...]
// Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
// immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
// be preserved and restored when next starting.
//
// Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
// without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
// alongside the project.

"hot_exit": true,

// remember_open_files makes the application start up with the last set of
// open files. Changing this to false will have no effect if hot_exit is
// true

"remember_open_files": true,
[...]
```

Putting both to `false` value you will achieve that.